# How to include multiple rows of LaTeX code via the YAML header (header-includes field) in RMarkdown?

Tags: yaml, latex, r-markdown

I need to include the following code in a .tex file that is generated from a custom template via RMarkdown, in order to get rid of an [error](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1649). However, if I try it as below in the YAML heading:

```
header-includes: 
  \newenvironment{CSLReferences}%
  {}%
  {\par}
```

it gets parsed into the .tex file as single line, like `\newenvironment{CSLReferences}% {}% {\par}`, thus commenting out everything after `%`. So how can I change the YAML part so that it correctly gets interpreted as 3 different lines?

Comment: In your particular case of using this definition in the header, you wouldn't need the `%` anyway ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials & searching this works (found a solution while writing the question):

```
header-includes:
  - "\\newenvironment{CSLReferences}%"
  - "{}%"
  - "{\\par}"
```

Interestingly, I couldn't find much [in the official documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html).

---

EDIT:
As @samcarter mentioned in the comments & an answer, in this particular case a single line would've been enough, as

```
header-includes:
   \newenvironment{CSLReferences}{}{\par}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about the markdown parsing, you can write the command in a single line:

```
header-includes: 
    \newenvironment{CSLReferences}{}{\par}
```

---

Alternatively avoid all these annoying problems with markdown parsing and put your definition in a .tex file which you can include via

```
includes:
  in_header: header.tex
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, sometimes more than one line is required, which is why I marked my answer.